# Do I need any of these styles on img2?

Tags: html, css, image

Do I need any of these codes on img2, and that they are useless, or do I keep any of them?

```
background-position:center;
```

When that is removed, it's still centered, so I'm not sure how useful that code is.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

When I increase the background space, and put, background -repeat; repeat; nothing happens.
So, I'm not sure how useful that code is.

```
background-size: 180px 180px;
```

When I remove that from the code, nothing happens, so I'm not sure how useful that code is.

```
 .img2 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position:center;
    background-size: 180px 180px;
  }
```

With them removed:

https://jsfiddle.net/yyqcgvpL/1/

What do you say?

Also, is there a specific reason why these 2 style codes don't function, or are disabled on img2?

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

or even repeat

```
background-position:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
background:cover;
```

It will fill out the whole page

Answer (score 0):

> > background-position: center;

It is equal to 50% in the horizontal position and 50% in the vertical position.

> > background-repeat: no-repeat;

The background image is displayed only once and is positioned away from the text.

> > background-size: 180px 180px;

It will be useful for fixing the size on different devices.

Can be used to fix and smooth your objects.
You can visit here for details :  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp